# Hadoop and Cassandra benchmarking

Tags: hadoop, docker, cassandra, benchmarking, stress-testing

I have built recently a `Hadoop` - `Cloudera cluster` and `Cassandra` cluster with 2 nodes. I would like to make now some benchmarking, collect some data about resource usage.
I've searched a lot and found `HiBench` and `Cassandra` stress tool. I don't want to compare with other systems, I would like to mesure my own, but it is difficult to imagine, how can I get real and correct values. Cluster consists of 2 virtual machines, created with `KVM`. `Cassandra` is in `Docker` containers. Hard to interpret, how to analyze this system, without getting false results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks

> Cluster consists of 2 virtual machines, created with KVM

Don't use virtual machines if you want to benchmark **performance**. Indeed Cassandra performs sequential writes on disk to optimize scan operations. By using virtual machines and shared disks, the benefit of sequential writes is lost because the hypervisor can *re-order* and dispatch contiguous data on different disk sectors, thus destroying the previous optimization for sequential scans

One alternative is to ensure that you have a **dedicated disk** for each VM.

If you're not doing performance benchmark, ignore the above comment

Second advice, use **real** data set e.g. big data set that **do not fit into memory** so that you can see how each technology behaves. Read this for more details: http://www.nextplatform.com/2016/02/19/the-myth-of-in-memory-computing/

Comment: Thanks a lot! First of all, how can be analized/benchmarked this system. I can't modify this now, but would like to show something about resources and its usage maybe. What wouldn't causes false results in this case?

Comment: With virtual machines, you can test every thing except performance: high availability (what if a node is powered off during the test ?), consistency of the data etc ...

Comment: But these data can't be analyzed. It isn't suitable for statistical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use yahoo cloud serving benchmark to benchmark your Cassandra cluster. Below is the link to it and the corresponding git repository.

https://research.yahoo.com/news/yahoo-cloud-serving-benchmark/
https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB

The benchmark is quite flexible and has a lot of parameters that can be changed to fully understand the cluster behavior and properties. However, 
one key drawback of this framework is that it uses random data by default.
But, you can tweak the code to use it for your own data and then, it should probably suit your needs.